# How to store JavaScript in a JavaScript array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm making a game in JavaScript. The basic idea is to have several buttons that use on.click to perform actions (Fight Monster, Dig for Treasure, etc).

One button loads the next adventure. I have an array containing all the adventures with the values "description" (d), "illustration" (i), and "buttons" (b). The description and illustration HTML show up just fine, but the javascript in the new "Get Flask" button does nothing. Escaping characters doesn't seem to help. Is there a better way to do this?

"Load next adventure" button code: (first couple of lines pick a number randomly up to 5, it has problems that I'll work on next)

```
<button type="button" 
   onclick="highLevel = y-1; 
            while (y >highLevel){ y = Math.round(Math.random() * 5)};
            document.getElementById('description').innerHTML = adventure[y].d;
            document.getElementById('illustration').innerHTML = adventure[y].i;
            document.getElementById('buttons').innerHTML = adventure[y].b"
>Begin</button>
```

Array code:

```
adventure[y++]={
d:"Adventure 1",
i:"<img src='cave_entrance.jpg' alt='cave entrance' /><figcaption></figcaption>",
b:"<button  type=&quot;button&quot; onclick=&quot;window.alert&#40;'Ye cannot get flask'&#41;&quot;>Get Flask</button>"
}
```

For more details, see the code at: https://gist.github.com/janchor/5063f56da41d3e32c825ff154c6bd3be

Comment: Tip: don't put any JS code in your HTML attributes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't change your code much, just fixed what you said :)

```js
function beginClick() {
  var highLevel = y - 1;
  y = Math.floor(Math.random() * highLevel);
  document.getElementById('description').innerHTML = adventure[y].d;
  document.getElementById('illustration').innerHTML = adventure[y].i;
  document.getElementById('buttons').innerHTML = adventure[y].b
}


var adventure = [];
var y = 0;
adventure[y++] = {
  d: "Adventure 1",
  i: "<img src='cave_entrance.jpg' alt='cave entrance' /><figcaption></figcaption>",
  b: "<button  type='button'; onclick='adventure[y].actionGetFlask()'>Get Flask</button>",
  actionGetFlask: function() {
    alert('Ye cannot get flask');
  }
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="beginClick()">Begin</button>
<div id="description"></div>
<div id="illustration"></div>
<div id="buttons"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have onclick call a function and move your logic into that.

```js
var adventure = {
  d: "Adventure 1",
  i: "<img src='cave_entrance.jpg' alt='cave entrance' /><figcaption></figcaption>",
  b: "<button  type=&quot;button&quot; onclick=&quot;window.alert&#40;'Ye cannot get flask'&#41;&quot;>Get Flask</button>"
}


function loadHtml() {
  document.getElementById('description').innerHTML = adventure.d;
  document.getElementById('illustration').innerHTML = adventure.i;
  document.getElementById('buttons').innerHTML = adventure.b
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="loadHtml()">Begin</button>

<div id="description"></div>
<div id="illustration"></div>
<div id="buttons"></div>
```